# Wait a process is fully started

Tags: java, process, runtime, wait

I'm launching a jar file with a Runtime and I would like to proceed only when the jar file is fully started.
It works with a Thread.sleep() but I would like to have the exact duration to sleep and not an arbitrary duration.

I read that the waitFor() wait until the process is ended but it isn't what I want.

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
process = runtime.exec("java -jar app.jar");
// wait until app fully started
...
```

Comment: What are you calling "fully started" ?

Comment: When my jar have finish initialisation. It's a javafx application.

Comment: Maybe you could read from `process.getInputStream()` until there is a particular string .

Comment: I would prefer not to modify the jar, and be independent from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only you as a developer can decide if the application is fully initialised.

For instance, add logic in you application, which creates a regular empty file(let's say it `app.started`). Then after `runtime.exec()` check if the file exist with some delay.

Comment: I wouldn't change the jar file, I'm probably using the wrong way to do what I want. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: np. in any case, if you cannot change the jar file maybe it's possible to find out what is going on during initialization step from developers or docs. maybe it opens some sockets of creates temporary files, what can be used as formal condition to check if init step is done.